# Order-safe value passing from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

If I pass an array from php to js:

```
 var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

Is it true that the `i`th element js array and the php array will refer to the same data?

Comment: Currently it won't work but all you need to do to fix it is replace `<?php echo $array[i].thumbnail ?>` with `someArray[i].thumbnail`.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question with the code, but it seems to drag away the attention from the question. I'll remove the code snippet.

Comment: The answer to your question is 'yes', both arrays will be in the same order so `$array[0]` will have the same value as `array[0]` and so on.

Comment: @Joe Great! Too bad I cannot accept comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is **yes** for index-based arrays. On associative arrays, that translate to js objects, what json_encode does doesn't really matter, as JavaScript does not guarantee any particular key order when iterating over the keys (with for..in).

Comment: "ith" implies a numberic key. Even if it gave back something like {"2":"b","0":a"}, you can easily numerically sort the object keys so that JS's array[i] is the same as $arr[$i] in php...

Comment: @dandavis I know the question is about numerical keys, but I thought the answer should also mention what happens with associative arrays. Concerning your object example, I don't see any reason for manually sorting the keys, since you might loose the order again when looping. Unless you convert the object to an actual array.

Comment: i was thinking something like Object.keys(arr).sort(fnDiff).forEach, or arr.length=Object.keys(arr); [].slice.call(arr).forEach. In other words, a just in time sort, not an Object property re-arrangement. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

what are you trying here? mixing php and js?

You should use the function's parameter you pass: `e`.

```
var someArray = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    infoWindow.setContent(createDivForElement(someArray[i]) );
}

function createDivForElement(e) {
    var result = '<div>';
    result += '<img src=' + e.thumbail + '/>'; 
    result += '</div>'
    return result;
}
```

You already pass `someArray[i]`, you can address inside of the function with `e`. Then you don't need to involve any PHP in the function. You only need PHP here to pass the data to JS.

---

Always keep in mind that once you put PHP somewhere in, it won't change on the client-side.

Comment: This is just a sample code I tried to write to show what I want to ask about. I'm just curious about the rules of array-passing in a similar situation.

Comment: @Croo this is what I just have explained here. pass the PHP array to some js variable, and then use the variable only in combination with JS. No manipulation of a function's parameters with PHP!

Comment: This is nice to know as a rule, thanks! I understand now that my original code snippet had problems. But my question was about how array passing works in this context. I removed the code snippet to clarify my question.

Comment: @Croo yes, it'll be the same, clearly. But as your snippet was totally wrong, I thought you did mainly want to know what was bugging here?